# apache second alias does'nt work

Tags: apache, alias

I have an alias on apache like this: Alias “/images” “/home/user1/data” Now I want to have a second alias like this: Alias “/images/charts” “/home/user1/meta/output”

But it isn't working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#order)

> (...) the Aliases and Redirects are processed in the order they appear in
>   the configuration files, with the first match taking precedence.
>
> For this reason, when two or more of these directives apply to the
>   same sub-path, you must list the most specific path first in order for
>   all the directives to have an effect. For example, the following
>   configuration will work as expected:
>
> ```
> Alias "/foo/bar" "/baz"
> Alias "/foo" "/gaq"
> ```